# why solidity function returns always false even if it should returns true?

Tags: solidity, remix

Here is my problem. I have a contract in solidity :

```
contract test {
    function testfunc(uint _number) external pure returns (bool) {
       return _number >= 0;
    }
}
```

Here is example :

[image]

This function retuns always false, even if I set a positive number... why ? it's not logic...

Do you have an explanation ?

Thanks for all,

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

[image: example]

it is returning true, try to redeploy the contract.

Comment: I found the error.... if I deploy my contract on a specific address, it's not working. I have to deploy without indicate a specific address....